I want my modified image size for screen mobile not for large device like pc
Hello i have a image that need to be sized like i want for mobile device the problem is that when i put the size i want for mobile device ( smaller device ) the size apply for large device too as the screen show
But i want to modifie the size and the position when it’s on small device the only thing is that when i do changes it’s also changing the large device too Even when i do « sm:-300 » for example
here is my code
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { MouseParallaxChild, MouseParallaxContainer } from "react-parallax-mouse";

const AuthLayout = () => {
  const IsAuthenthicated = false;
  return (
    <>
      {IsAuthenthicated ? (
        <Navigate to ="/" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <section className="flex flex-1 justify-center items-center flex-col py-10">
            <Outlet />
          </section>

          {/* Utilisation de l'image en tant que fond d'écran */}
          <div
            className="wall1 hover-blur sm:63 xl:block h-screen w-screen object-cover bg-no-repeat absolute top-0 left-0 z-0"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url("/assets/images/wall1.png")`  }}
          />

          {/* Votre contenu ici */}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default AuthLayout



I'm having a hard time understanding what the desired result is. Could you provide an example of how your form / website should look?

But i want to modifie the size and the position when it’s on small device the only thing is that when i do changes it’s also changing the large device too Even when i do « sm:-300 » for example

your div size is 100vh and 100vw, background-image: cover ...
it works perfect, according your code..
you shall provide background image sizes ...
this is example how you can achieve that using tailwind arbitrary values (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-size#arbitrary-values):
bg-[length:200px_100px]
md:bg-[length:300px_150px]
lg:bg-[length:400px_200px]

also position will be needed after that ...
use bg-center class or other position manipulator class

But i want to modifie the size and the position when it’s on small device the only thing is that when i do changes it’s also changing the large device too Even when i do « sm:-300 » for example

sm:-300 does not exist... may you mean sm:w-[300px]
